# How to filter elements in a list that occur only once

Tags: python, list, filter

I need to filter and discard elements in a list that occur only once.

I have the following list of integers as input. I need to make a new list that contains only elements that do not have singular appearances.

```
item_list = [502, 502, 1341, 1342, 1500, 1500, 2521, 2521, 3078, 3688, 4191, 5185, 5701, 5701]
```

The desired output list would be like:

```
item_list = [502, 502, 1500, 1500, 2521, 2521, 5701, 5701]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

item_list = [502, 502, 1341, 1342, 1500, 1500, 2521, 2521, 3078, 3688, 4191, 5185, 5701, 5701]

c = Counter(item_list)
out = [i for i in item_list if c[i] > 1]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[502, 502, 1500, 1500, 2521, 2521, 5701, 5701]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make a new list which checks every value that that doesn't occur 1, then you set the list to the new list:

```
item_list = [502, 502, 1341, 1342, 1500, 1500, 2521, 2521, 3078, 3688, 4191, 
5185, 5701, 5701]

new_list = [i for i in item_list if i != 1]

item_list = new_list

print(item_list)
```

Comment: If you run the exact code you posted, you'll see it doesn't work. The list comprehension is excluding the value `1`, not values that appear once.

Comment: Also, with list comprehension there's no need to create a temporal variable. You can do `item_list  = [i for i in item_list if ...]`.